# mysql datetime comparison query syntax not working for me

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime

I have a very simple select query in mysql that involve a filter of the date column. I simply cannot find where my errors is.
Here is the query and error message:

```
SELECT * FROM temp WHERE date > '2013-12-27 03:12:14';
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your....blablabla...near '?date > '2013-12-27 03:12:14'' at line 1
```

the console wouldnt allow me to copy, but in my data structure, there is a field named "date", type is "datetime", Null is yes, Default Null.

Where did i go wrong?

thanks a lot for the helps!
[edit] here is a
[screenshot](http://postimg.org/image/4lmqv0y8f/)

[update]
As suggested, I have *retyped* the statement and it worked. Although it solved the issue, i am more confused than ever. If someone could enlighten me, please do.
thank you all.

Comment: I dont think that error refers to your query.

Comment: Your query, as written, works fine.  See http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c3c2d/1.

Comment: If console is not allowing to copy, you just capture the screen shot and attach here.

Comment: Thanks Ravinder. Just tried, it said i need 10 reputations...This is my first post....
Hello everyone, by the way!

Comment: There are many free sites to post and publish images.

Comment: May I know which console are you working on? and OS?

Comment: windows 8, wamp\bin\mysql\mysql5.6.12\bin\mysql.exe

Comment: just added a screenshot link. Thanks Ravinder.

Comment: On your MySQL console, *retype the statement* and it should work now. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this query
SELECT * FROM temp WHERE date > date('2013-12-27 03:12:14');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use backticks in date and check if it works

select * from temp where `date` > '2013-12-27 03:12:14';

Comment: Thanks! tried that, but didn't work. As you see above, Ravinder's suggestion of retyping the command actually worked. I have checked very carefully that there are no typos in the first try, i have no idea what retyping had done to change anything. but... i worked. Now i look like an idiot.